# Reading multiple child objects from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, ado.net

I have the need to load in a large object with all its children from my SQL Server database.

I plumped for using `FOR XML` in the queries and then using an `XmlReader` before deserialising the lot into the classes needed much like this:

```
SELECT  
    MyClass.* ,
    (SELECT    
         ChildClass1.[ID],
         ChildClass1.[Description]
     FROM      
         [dbo].[ChildClass1Table] ChildClass1
     JOIN 
         dbo.LinkyTable lt ON lt.ChildClass1ID = ChildClass1.ID
     WHERE     
         lt.CID = MyClass.ID
     FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('ChildClass1'), TYPE, ELEMENTS),
    (SELECT    
         ChildClass2.[ID], ChildClass2.[Description]
     FROM      
         [dbo].[ChildClass1Table] ChildClass2
     JOIN 
         dbo.LinkyTable2 lt2 ON lt.ChildClass2ID = ChildClass2.ID
     WHERE     
         lt2.CID = MyClass.ID
     FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('ChildClass2'), TYPE, ELEMENTS) 
FROM 
    ...etc - for a fair few more
```

C# code:

```
using (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
{
        if (xmlr.Read())
        {
            string xml = string.Empty;

            while (xmlr.ReadState != System.Xml.ReadState.EndOfFile)
            {
                xml = xmlr.ReadOuterXml();
            }

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

            using (var stream = new StringReader(xml))
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                MyClass b = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                return b;
            }
        }
    }
```

This works well, and I really have no issue with it - other than I ideally would like to use the repository pattern to grab all my objects from the DB and would rather use the `IDbConnection` / `IDbCommand` rather than the concrete SQL Server classes which are necessary to use the `XmlReader`.

My question is, is there another way that these child objects can be loaded in (without making multiple round trips to the DB for each child (and grandchild class)) using standard readers ?

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Is the pure ADO.NET an option?

Guess we have the following stored procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.GetParents
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    declare @Parents table (Id int, Name varchar(50));
    declare @Children table (Id int, ParentId int, Name varchar(50));

    insert into @Parents values 
        (1, 'First parent'),
        (1, 'First parent'),
        (1, 'First parent');

    insert into @Children values 
        (1, 1, 'First child of first parent'),
        (2, 1, 'Second child of first parent'),
        (3, 1, 'Third child of first parent'),
        (4, 2, 'First child of second parent'),
        (5, 2, 'Second child of second parent'),
        (6, 2, 'Third child of second parent'),
        (7, 3, 'First child of third parent'),
        (8, 3, 'Second child of third parent'),
        (9, 3, 'Third child of third parent');

    select * from @Parents order by Id;

    select * from @Children order by ParentId, Id;
end;
```

and a pair of classes:

```
public class Parent {
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children {get; set; }
}
public class Child {
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public int ParentId {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

the following code reads a list of parents with their children:

```
var parents = new List<Parent>();
var children = new List<Child>();

var connectionString=@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "GetParents";

    connection.Open();

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read()) 
            parents.Add(new Parent {Id = reader.GetInt32(0), Name = reader.GetString(1) });

        reader.NextResult();

        while (reader.Read()) 
            children.Add(new Child {Id = reader.GetInt32(0), ParentId = reader.GetInt32(1), Name = reader.GetString(2) });
    }
}

// combination of two collections

var childEnumerator = children.GetEnumerator();
var child = childEnumerator.MoveNext() ? childEnumerator.Current : null;

foreach (var parent in parents)
{
    parent.Children = new List<Child>();

    while (child != null && child.ParentId == parent.Id)
    {
        parent.Children.Add(child);
        child = childEnumerator.MoveNext() ? childEnumerator.Current : null;
    }
}
```

Of course the combination of two collections can be done simplier, like:

```
foreach (var parent in parents)
{
    parent.Children = new List<Child>();

    foreach (var child in children) 
    {
        parent.Children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

but when two recordsets are sorted properly then GetEnumerator() makes the process much faster.

Comment: thanks for the reply, that looks fine for a couple of child properties, but there are 12 on my top level object, and some have a fair number of properties themselved. that might get very messy

Comment: For such a case, the following library has been specially created — to reduce the mess while reading and saving graphs of objects: https://github.com/lobodava/artisan-orm

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution i'm using. 
The procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetParentsWithChildren] 
@ParentId int = null
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 select * from Parents
 where (@ParentId IS NULL OR Id = @ParentId)    
 order by Id;

select * from Children
where (@ParentId IS NULL OR ParentId = @ParentId )  
order by ParentId, Id;
END
```

You declare your models as needed. You can get only one or all parents, depending on passed parameter that I've commented out here.

Here's function that will get the list:

```
    public List<Partner> GetParentsWithChildren()
    {
        List<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>();
        List<Child> children = new List<Child>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetPartnersWithDevices", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentId", 1);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {                   
                parents = GetModelFromReader<Parent>(reader);

                reader.NextResult();                    

                children = GetModelFromReader<Child>(reader);
            }

            foreach (Parent parent in parents)
            {
                parent.Children = children.Where(x => x.ParentId == parent.Id).ToList();
            }
        }
        return partners;
    }
```

Here i created a generic function that will return a list of passed object.
The only rule is that the model props are named as fields in table, and prop types should be the same as in table or all strings. It will work nevertheless.
If you've owerriden default constructor in your model, add it. Model must have a default constructor.

```
    private List<T> GetModelFromReader<T>(SqlDataReader reader) where T : new()
    {
        List<T> listModels = new List<T>();

        var modelItem = new T();

        var modelType = modelItem.GetType();
        var modelProps = modelType.GetProperties();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
           var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                       .Select(reader.GetName)
                       .ToList();
            foreach (var prop in inProps)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (columns.Contains(prop.Name))
                    {
                        var value = reader[prop.Name];
                        if (ReferenceEquals(value, DBNull.Value))
                        {
                            value = null;
                        }                            
                        var propType = prop.PropertyType;
                        Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType) ?? propType;
                        value = (value == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, t);

                        prop.SetValue(modelItem, value);
                    }                       
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { //it type not the same will try to convert to string and cast.
                  //It will work fine without this part if types are the same.
                  //I recommend that you set types properly and comment out this part
                    try
                    {
                        var strValue = reader[prop.Name].ToString();
                        var value = Convert.ChangeType(strValue, prop.PropertyType);
                        prop.SetValue(modelItem, value);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
            listModels.Add(modelItem);
            modelItem = new T();
        }
        return listModels;
    }
```